# Enable GtkInspector via shortcuts

Tags: gtk3

How can I enable the new GtkInspector that comes with GTK 3.14?

The changelog says that either <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> open the inspector, and if `org.gtk.Settings.Debug.enable-inspector-keybinding` is set to `true`. I meet all of the above conditions, but neither shortcut works for me in any GTK 3 application.

Using `export GTK_DEBUG=interactive` does work, but I'm wondering why the shortcuts don't.

Comment: Maybe something is grabbing your input or you have system-wide hotkey under these combinations?